# Executing a python script from the terminal in Unix

Tags: python

I have a python script and I can't figure how to execute it in the terminal. The script has the `#!/usr/bin/python` at the beginning, is executable and I've tried locating myself in the right directory and `python name.py` but what I want to print (ergo what the script says it should print) doesn't print in the terminal.

I feel I'm missing something... I just started with this so... Help!

Comment: Please show us your code. It's very difficult to know what is going on without being able to see anything

Comment: If you enter the python shell and execute the code in your script, does it work? It might be something wrong with the script itself

Comment: Yes the code works if I introduce it directly to the python shell!

Answer (score 3):

If name.py is executable, you can run it using:

```
./name.py
```

As for the `#!`, it is better to use as a first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This way path to python interpreter is not hardcoded, the first `python` found in `$PATH` is used instead. 
Also: it makes your script to run in fresh environment (you can see `man env` for more information).

Comment: To clarify the answer: unlike Windows, Unix does not search for executable files in current directory, so to execute a script that's not referenced from `PATH` variable, one has to state current folder explicitly. Thus, `./script.py` instead of simply `script.py`